# Why do I sometimes get repeatedly prompted with ">" in the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, prompt

Alright, when I run certain commands the wrong way, (misspelled, etc.) The terminal outputs this: `>` instead of `computername:workingfolder username$`, and when I type enter it goes like this:

```
>

>

>
```

That would be if I pressed enter 3 times.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`>` is the default continuation prompt.That is what you will see if what you entered before had unbalanced quote marks.

As an example, type a single quote on the command line followed by a few `enter` keys:

```
$ '
> 
> 
>
```

The continuation prompts will occur until you either

- (a) complete the command with a closing quote mark

  or
- (b) type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to finish input, at which point the shell will respond with an error message about the unbalanced quotes,

  or
- (c) type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which will abort the command that you were entering.

#### How this is useful

Sometime, you may want to enter a string which contains embedded new lines.  You can do that as follows:

```
$ paragraph='first line
> second line
> third line
> end'
```

Now, when we display that shell variable, you can see that the prompts have disappeared but the newlines are retained:

```
$ echo "$paragraph"
first line
second line
third line
end
```

Answer (score 16):

That will happen if you have an unclosed quote in your command. That's something like:

```
$ echo "test here
>
>
...
```

You can exit that mode by closing the quote (write a `"` or `'`, or whatever your open quote is). It could also be a brace-delimited block, a partially-complete `for-do` or `while-do` loop, or certain other constructs. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to cancel this command (then press <kbd>Up</kbd> to revise it).

This can sometimes happen without an obvious missing quote when [parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or [history](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) expansions occur where you didn't expect them.

---

The `>` is your [`PS2`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PS2) ("secondary prompt") value. You can change that to something else to remind you what's happened:

```
PS2="Unclosed >"
```

in your `.bashrc` will make it print `Unclosed >` at the start of each line instead.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, you also get the continuation prompt when you type a `\` as the last character on a line.

Comment: (For me, this usually happens by accident, as the backslash is frighteningly close to the Enter key.)

Comment: Not on [my keyboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1167?m=6186584#6186584), it isn't.

Comment: @TRiG You mean, you often type # by accident instead of \? Right...

Answer (score 7):

The answer lies in this cryptic mention in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PS2):

> ### 5.1 Bourne Shell Variables
>
> *[...]*
>
> - `PS1`: The primary prompt string. The default value is ‘`\s-\v\$`’. See [Printing a Prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt), for the complete list of escape sequences that are expanded before `PS1` is displayed.
> - `PS2`: The secondary prompt string. The default value is ‘`>`’.

… [followed by](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior):

> #### 6.3.3 Interactive Shell Behavior
>
> 3. Bash expands and displays `PS1` before reading the first line of a command, and expands and displays `PS2` before reading the second and subsequent lines of a multi-line command.

So, the `>` prompt appears if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and Bash determines that the command is incomplete.  That could be because:

- The character before the newline is a `\`, which is treated as a [line continuation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Escape-Character).
- You have an incomplete string (mismatched quotes or unterminated here-doc) or some other mismatched delimiters, such as `$()`, `()`, ``` `` ```.
- You have started a function definition, a `for` loop, a `while` loop, or a `case`.

If you are seeing the secondary prompt due to an unintentional typing error, hit <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to return to the primary prompt.

Comment: You also get the secondary prompt when you're typing into a here-doc. But this is less likely to happen by accident than the others.

Answer (score 6):

The shell waiting for you to complete the command. Maybe there's a unclosed quote somewhere or it thinks you are starting a "for" loop and waits for the user to finish typing