# What does " command do in terminal?

Tags: shell, command-line, quoting

Recently, I opened terminal and started typing everything i can, after which i accidentally put `"` and something like python shell was initialised:

```bsh
muhammadrasul@AMR:~/Desktop$ lksdflaflakd;kfa;lk"
> a
> s
> 
> fd
> sfs
> fs
>
```

Then I realised that it works just for `"` as well. So, what that environment actually is and why does it ignore everything before that `"`?

Comment: Related: [Why do I sometimes get repeatedly prompted with “>” in the terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158997/why-do-i-sometimes-get-repeatedly-prompted-with-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Please post text as text (so my blind friend can read it).

Comment: actually it is not related to text at all, i wanted to show what it looks like

Comment: a python-like shell would do something when you end a line, even if it's just an error about syntax or using an undefined variable

Comment: @steeldriver, eh, looks like a straight-on duplicate to me...

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  the politically correct term is `visually challenged`, i think

Comment: @Jsotola I asked her. She says that seeing is not a challenge, as there seems to be nothing she can do to be able to see, because she is blind.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor i guess that political correctness can be nonsense sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"` starts a string. The string lasts until the next `"` (except that `\"` put a `"` in the string and doesn't end the string). The string can contain newlines. So after entering a single `"`, the shell keeps reading input, because the string is unfinished.

When you terminate the string with another `"`, the shell will start executing the command. That's when it will complain that each of the commands is not found.

The `>`  prompt is the shell's way to say that it's expecting more input. You can customize it through the variable `PS2`, which is analogous to `PS1`, but for continuation lines.

Comment: so, if it takes a string, and if there is no such command like in the given string, it will say command not found, but otherwise will it execute that command?

Comment: @Muhammadrasul Yes, if you have a command that contains a newline character (which is possible, but extremely unusual), and you type that command, it will execute that command.

Comment: huge thanks, I've learnt something useful!

Comment: and `'` woks the same as `"`, almost like in python

Comment: @Muhammadrasul In the shell, `'` works almost the same as `"`. The difference is that between `'`, no character is special, even `\ `. So you can't have a `'` inside `'…'` at all. You have to write `echo 'D'\''oh'` to get `D'oh` (or of course write it some other way such as `echo D\'oh` or `echo "D'oh"`).