# Quote characters work as commands that redirect to the standard input

Tags: shell, command-line, command, stdin

I am a student and I am trying an excercise that involves assigning a word with quotes, double quotes and other symbols to a file name.

The problem is that I am not getting the expected results.
I am using the scape bar to scape the symbols, but when I list the name of the file this appears with unexpected single quotes at the beginning and the end of the file name and scape bars surrounded by single quotes before the single quotes that are supposed to be part of the file name. This is a bit confusing, I'll show you:

```
$ echo > \"\\\?\$\*\'\'\*\$\?\\\"
```

I expect this:

```
$ ls
"\?$*''*$?\"
```

but I get this instead:

```
$ ls
'"\?$*'\'''\''*$?\"'
```

I've tried to do it in other ways such as wrapping the double quotes in single quotes and viceversa, but I always get the same result. I already had made the same excercise in other computer and it worked perfectly. What is more intriguing is that I've discovered that both the single and the double quote work as a command to redirect to the standard input, what, I suspect, has to do with the unexpected name display:

```
$ '
> 

$ "
>
```

The commands don't seem to work for anything else than to display the standard input. Is this normal at all? What is going on? What can I do?

Comment: use `ls -N` to print the filename literally ... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679

Comment: Thank you very much, that actually works!, but I want to get to the bottom of this, why do the quote characters work as commands?

Comment: They don't, `>` is the continuation prompt... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158997

Comment: @Daniel not quite sure how to interpret your question there, but `ls` without `-N` just tries to quote "problematic" file names as necessary.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much! I have one last question. Why is that when I've worked in other computers I didn't need to include -N to display the list as I expected, is just a matter of configuration?

Comment: It's a matter of `ls` version. See Padraig Brady's answer to the question I linked to in my 1st comment... It's also possible that same  `ls` version  was aliased to `ls -N` then yes, it's a matter of configuration...

Comment: Please take your found solution and post it as an _answer_ to this question, and mark it as resolved.  This will aid future searchers in that it will show that a solution has been found, and also not draw other folks here to answer something that already has been answered.

Comment: @DopeGhoti ok, thank you, I will. Apparently I have to wait for 10 hours before I can mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I expected `ls` to work as `ls -N`. It seems in other machines the expected behaviour was different due to version or maybe configuration issues. About the quotes, it seems that they are not commands, but the prompt appears when the quotes are not properly closed as it interprets it as unfinished. All the explanations and relevant links are in the comments, thanks to @don_crissti and @Marcus Müller.